R New Variable if_else with longitudinal data
I am currently working on longitudinal data in which I have participants BMI category (normal, overweight, and obese) for three time points, age 7, 9, and 11. I would like to create one new variable that states whether a participant was always normal/overweight/obese, sometimes normal/overweight/obese, or never normal/overweight/obese. Thank you!
Below is the code I ran and R populated back the following error code: "Error in mutate(): In argument: BMICAT_TRAJ = if_else(...).
Caused by error in if_else():
! argument "false" is missing, with no default"
Data1 <- Data1 %>%
mutate(BMICAT_TRAJ =
if_else(BMICAT_7 == "Normal" & BMICAT_9 == "Normal" & BMICAT_11 == "Normal", "Always Normal",
if_else(BMICAT_7 == "Overweight" & BMICAT_9 == "Overweight" & BMICAT_11 == "Overweight", "Always Overweight",
if_else(BMICAT_7 == "Obese" & BMICAT_9 == "Obese" & BMICAT_11 == "Obese", "Always Obese",
     if_else(BMICAT_7 == "Normal" & BMICAT_9 != "Normal" | BMICAT_11 != "Normal", "Sometimes Normal",
     if_else(BMICAT_7 == "Overweight" & BMICAT_9 != "Overweight" | BMICAT_11 != "Overweight", "Sometimes Overweight",
     if_else(BMICAT_7 == "Obese" & BMICAT_9 != "Obese" | BMICAT_11 != "Obese", "Sometimes Obese",
     
     if_else(BMICAT_9 == "Normal" & BMICAT_7 != "Normal" | BMICAT_11 != "Normal", "Sometimes Normal",
     if_else(BMICAT_9 == "Overweight" & BMICAT_7 != "Overweight" | BMICAT_11 != "Overweight", "Sometimes Overweight",
     if_else(BMICAT_9 == "Obese" & BMICAT_7 != "Obese" | BMICAT_11 != "Obese", "Sometimes Obese",
     
     if_else(BMICAT_11 == "Normal" & BMICAT_9 != "Normal" | BMICAT_7 != "Normal", "Sometimes Normal",
     if_else(BMICAT_11 == "Overweight" & BMICAT_9 != "Overweight" | BMICAT_7 != "Overweight", "Sometimes Overweight",
     if_else(BMICAT_11 == "Obese" & BMICAT_9 != "Obese" | BMICAT_7 != "Obese", "Sometimes Obese"),
     
     
     if_else(BMICAT_7 != "Normal" & BMICAT_9 != "Normal" & BMICAT_11 != "Normal", "Never Normal",
     if_else(BMICAT_7 != "Overweight" & BMICAT_9 != "Overweight" & BMICAT_11 != "Overweight", "Never Overweight",
     if_else(BMICAT_7 != "Obese" & BMICAT_9 != "Obese" & BMICAT_11 != "Obese", "Never Obese", "NA")))))))))))))))


It will be much easier to help you if you provide a sample of your dataset. If you run dput(Data1) and add the result to a codeblock in your question as an edit, that will help. The dput) result will look something like structure(list(...)). If your data are too large to share, simply run dput(head(Data1,20)) instead. Be sure to ensure no confidential data are included. Thanks.
